# Express list comprehension using numpy array indexing

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a 3d array, P, of shape (32, 2, 10) - 32 samples each of shape (2, 10) - and a 1d array, A, of shape (32,). The values in A are either 0 or 1 and are used to select either the first or second row per sample. I have a working solution using a list comprehension as shown below:

```
result = np.array([P[i, A[i]] for i in range(32)])
```

Is it possible to express this using just array indexing? That is, is there an equivalent expression of the form:

```
result = P[MAGIC_HERE]
```

If so, which would be less computationally expensive (faster)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use numpy's indexing like so:

```
result = P[np.arange(32), A[np.arange(32)]]
```

Comment: That was pretty fast. Thanks!